# Infix notation a un arbol de expresion de manera recursiva

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

estoy tratando de convertir un string infix a un arbol de expresion de manera recursiva, para esto anexo el algoritmo, pero no logro ver porque al estar haciendo el Parseo, obtengo un error de NullerPointerException, en teoria iria bien, y no logro ver lo que pasa con el debugger.
Si alguno logra ver lo que no veo, o si algo estoy entendiendo mal, se los agradeceria.
Cualquier idea es bienvenida.

Para hacer mas facil el parseo, hago uso excesivo de parentesis para agrupar todo y sea mas facil hacer el parsing

```
Algorithm

 1. node = new treeNode
 2. if string is a number
 3.   node.value = number extracted
 4.   return node
 5. endif
 6. node.op = extract operator
 7. node.left = parse (substring of string to the left of op)
 7. node.right = parse (substring of string to the right of op)
```

```
/**
 * ExpressionTree class
 */
public class ExpressionTree {
    private static class Node {
        int value;
        int op;
        Node left, right;
        boolean isNumber;
    }

    Node root;

    /**
     * Start parsing the equation
     * @param str equation
     */
    public void parsing(String str){
        root = parse(str);
    }
    /**
     * Empty constructor
     */
    ExpressionTree(){

    }
    Node parse(String str){
        Node node = new Node();
        try{
            int n = findRight(str,1);
            String left = str.substring(1,n+1);
            if (n == str.length()-1){
                String op = str.substring(1,str.length()-1);
                node.isNumber = true;
                node.value = getValue(op);
                System.out.println(" Returned Node" + " value " + node.value);
                return node;
            }
            int n2 = findLeft(str, str.length()-2);
            String right = str.substring(n2, str.length()-1);
            node.left = parse(left);
            node.right = parse(right);
            node.op = str.charAt(n+1);
            return node;
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException exception){
            System.out.println("Error parse : " + exception.getCause().toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the matching left parent
     * @param str equation
     * @param pos index to start searching
     * @return position of left parent
     */
    public int findLeft(String str, int pos) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        try {
            stack.push(str.charAt(pos));
            for (int i = pos + 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                char c = str.charAt(i);
                if (c == '(')
                    stack.push(c);
                else if (c == ')') {
                    stack.pop();
                    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Left i " + i);
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException exception) {
            System.out.println("ERROR findLeft: str " + str + " right = " + pos);
            System.out.println("Error :" + exception.getCause().toString());
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Converts String operand to his value
     * @param op string operand
     * @return value of operand
     */
    public int getValue(String op) {
        try{
            return Integer.parseInt(op);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the matching right parent
     * @param str equation
     * @param pos index to start searching
     * @return position of right parent
     */
    public int findRight(String str, int pos) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(str.charAt(pos));
        //System.out.println("findRight: str "+ str + " left = "+ pos);
        try {
            for (int i = pos+1; i < str.length(); i++){
                char c = str.charAt(i);
                if(c == '(')
                    stack.push(c);
                else if (c == ')'){
                    stack.pop();
                    if (stack.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println("Right i " + i);
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException exception) {
            System.out.println("ERROR findRight: str "+ str + " left = "+ pos);
            System.out.println("Error findRight : " + exception.getCause().toString());
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Start solving
     * @return solved expression tree
     */
    public int computeValue(){
        return compute(root);
    }

    /**
     * Solve the expression tree recursively
     * @param node node
     * @return value of expression tree
     */
    public int compute(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull Node node){
        if (node.isNumber){
            return node.value;
        }
        int left = compute(node.left);
        int right = compute(node.right);
        if (node.op == '+'){
            return left + right;
        }else if (node.op == '-'){
            return left - right;
        }else if (node.op == '*'){
            return left * right;
        }else if (node.op == '^'){
            return (int)Math.pow(left, right);//Temporal cast
        }else{
            return left / right;
        }
    }    
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String str;
        str = "((((35)-((3)*((3)+(2))))/4))";
        ExpressionTree expressionTree = new ExpressionTree();
        expressionTree.parsing(str);
        int v = expressionTree.computeValue();
        System.out.println(str + " = " + v);
    }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto

*Returned Node value 35 and NullPointerException*